# Loop after finish previous process

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to use for loop in puppeteer. However, it will open 11 chromium at a time. The script will cause my server crash. Is there any other way to let the code loop only after previous finished? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could use :

```
 const coursePage = await browser.newPage();
```

Then

```
  await coursePage.waitForNavigation();
```

And finally close after you have done your work

```
  await coursePage.close();
```

Reference : 
Loop : https://github.com/hiteshdua1/Automated_250_Udemy_Courses/blob/master/app.js#L18